# Can you pass parent function keyword arguments to a child function easily?

Tags: python

By this, I mean that often I have a function with a keyword argument, such as `debug=False`, and I want to pass this to a child function with the same keyword argument, which would result in something like `debug=debug`.

Here is an example:

```
def makeDirNearbyBuildings(lat, lon, lat1=None, lon1=None, area=1000, debug=False, debugimg=False):

  if lat1 == None:
    buildings = getNearbyBuildings(lat, lon, area=area, debug=debug)
```

This works, but isn't very readable.
Is there a programatically nicer way to do this in Python?

Comment: Use `**kwargs`?

Comment: What do you find unreadable?